# Sending email using CDO

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, cdo.message

I have a database which contains email address of recipients and a flag column. If the flag is "YES", a mail will be sent to that user. I want to accomplish this using CDO in my ASP.NET project. So, what may be the favorable routine for doing this. I am new to CDO. 
What I tried as a beginner is this:

```
CDO.Message oMsg = new CDO.Message();
        CDO.IConfiguration iConfg;
        iConfg = oMsg.Configuration;
        ADODB.Fields oFields;
        oFields = iConfg.Fields;
        ADODB.Field oField = oFields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"];
        oFields.Update();
        oMsg.Subject = "Test CDO";
        oMsg.From = "abc@xyz.com";
        oMsg.To = "someone@example.com";
        //oMsg.TextBody = "CDO Mail test";
        oMsg.HTMLBody = "CDO Mail test";
        oMsg.Send();
        Response.Write("Mail Sent");
```

But its not helping me what I want.

Comment: what do you mean it's not helping you do what you want? Is it erroring? If so what's the error? Do you know it's not working? Can you monitor the mailbox someone@example.com to see if the mail is arriving?

Comment: NO....its giving 'The \"SendUsing\" configuration value is invalid'. and secondly I want to pull email address from database. Also I am new to CDO, so i need some guidance using CDO through database\

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use CDO for mail sending in .NET. You should use the strongly typed `System.Net.Mail` namespace and the classes therin. Example code here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/432854

Comment: Matt Wilko is right. People don't use CDO any more. It is a pain. You will find much more help/examples if you use System.Net.Mail.  Is there some reason that you need to use CDO?

Comment: Well I accomplished what I needed through System.Net.Mail, just wanted CDO coz I am new in mailing techniques, not worked in this area, so first read about sending mail was through CDO.